# will "service httpd reload" reload new php.ini settings?

Tags: php, apache, ssh, terminal

I'm trying to enable shorthand in PHP via setting this:

```
short_open_tag = 1
```

I then execute:

```
service httpd reload
```

however the changes do not take effect. do I need to do "service apache2 reload" instead? or does "service httpd reload" normally work to load new php.ini settings?

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to

```
service apache2 reload
```

as php.ini settings changes require apache/nginx or whatever server to be reloaded

Comment: thanks.. so I know that will work, however I get an error when executing that. my question is more so if "service httpd reload" will ALSO work. thanks for your help!

Comment: AFAIK `httpd` and `apache2` are synonymous (different terms on different OSs/distributions)

Answer (score 3):

depends on the distro

Fedora based is "service httpd restart"
Debian based is "service apache2 restart"

Not sure on the other distro's

Comment: Arch Linux is "systemctl restart httpd"

Answer (score 1):

Using CentOS and Apache 2.4 you could use the following command to reload the apache configuration including php.ini

```
apachectl graceful
```